# Соседние элементы съезжают вниз

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Всем привет!
Делаю кастомный селект на основе плагина jQuery SelectmenuWidget (http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu) все вроде работает как я хочу, кроме одного:
 
Все элементы которые находятся на одной строке с селектом, сползают вниз.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

здесь текст должен находится по центру высоты, но почему-то тоже сползает вниз[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема? я по убирал все маргины, паддинги но толку ноль.
p.s. с css и версткой практически не знаком
Разметка:

```
            <div>

                <select class="reg_select_country">
                    <option value="+7">Россия +7</option>
                    <option value="+7">Казахстан +7</option>
                    <option value="+375">Белоруссия +375</option>
                </select>

                <span style="width:15%;font-size:11px;" id="reg_label_country">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;+7
                </span>

                <input type="text" name="phone" class="reg_input_phone" placeholder=" " style="width:48%;margin:0;position:relative;right:0">

            </div>
```

Js:

```
$('.reg_select_country').selectmenu({'width': true, position:{}});
```

CSS который я трогал в плагине:

```
.ui-selectmenu-menu {
    font-size: 15px;
}
.ui-selectmenu-menu .ui-menu  {
    color: #696969;
    background: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    max-height: 300px;
}

.ui-widget {
    font-size: 15px;
} 

.ui-selectmenu-button span.ui-selectmenu-text {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0.8em 2.1em 0.4em 1em;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: inherit;
    line-height: 1.4;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

/*Установка стиля при наведении на item*/
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus{
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    background: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;

}

.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #8e8e8e;
}

.ui-corner-all {
    border-radius: 0;
}

.reg_select_brithday + .ui-selectmenu-button {
    width: 87px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0;
}

.reg_select_brithmounth + .ui-selectmenu-button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0;
}

.reg_select_brithyear + .ui-selectmenu-button {
    width: 74px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0;
}

.reg_select_pol + .ui-selectmenu-button {
    width: 80px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0;
}

.reg_select_country + .ui-selectmenu-button {
    width: 35%;
    height: 50px;
}


.ui-state-default .ui-icon{
    background-image: url("/images/register/trg.png");
}

.ui-selectmenu-button:hover .ui-icon{
    background-image: url("/images/register/trg_hover.png");
}

.ui-icon-triangle-1-s {
    background-position: 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы элементы были в ряд, нужно в CSS к элементам дописать display: inline-block

Comment: к сожалению, не помогло

Comment: display: inline-block + vertical-align:middle;

Comment: Заработало! Хватило даже одного vertical-align:middle;